# How do I redirect URLs in a Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, redirect, laravel-5

I have experience using .htaccess files to redirect user requests from one place to another. However, I am new to Laravel and have never attempted to do redirects in Laravel.

What's the best way to do redirects in Laravel? Is it as simple as putting an .htaccess file in the project root and doing things like I normally would, or does Laravel have a special way of doing this?

For my specific use case, I want to redirect requests to images in an `img` directory to another publicly accessible path.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel has a helper function for redirects, here are some examples:

```
Route::get('dashboard', function () {
    return redirect('home/dashboard');
});
```

or from inside of an controller action:

```
return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
```

[Official Laravel Redirect Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is available at [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects) but you need to look at it. In your case you can use global redirect helper:

```
Route::get('route', function () {
    return redirect('anotherRoute');
});
```